# $AB$ is invertible but $A$ or $B$ is not invertible.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Searching for an example:

A Banach Space $X$, $A,B$ are operators on $X$ where $AB$ is invertible but $A$ or $B$ is not invertible.

For finite dimensional case we know that result so the example will come from infinite dimension.

Thank You.

Comment: that is true for finite dimension

Comment: is not left/right shift in right order invertible, but not otherwise?